# How do you use FirstOrDefault with Include?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

This works fine:

```
return Members
          .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Agreement.Equals(agreement));
```

But this throws an exception if it doesn't find a match:

```
 return Members
            .Include("Files")
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Agreement.Equals(agreement) &&
            !m.Files.Any(f => f.Status.Equals(12)));
```

So how can I get first/default (which may be null) when I'm using an Include?

The exception is:

> Unexpected Exception    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, ConstantExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, BinaryExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression
>   lambda, DbExpression input)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression
>   lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source,
>   DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NotTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, UnaryExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, BinaryExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression
>   lambda, DbExpression input)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression
>   lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source,
>   DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.AggregateTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, MethodCallExpression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter
>   parent, Expression linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression
>   linq)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source)

Comment: could you show the exception that is thrown?

Comment: Are you sure this is what's giving you the error? This should (as far as I can tell) be executed completely within the database.

Comment: @JensKloster It's long, but I edited to add it.

Comment: @Rob If I put a breakpoint at that line and right after, it's always right at that line that the exception shows up.

Comment: @pidacrep It looks like you are doing a `.Single()` not a `.FirstOrDefault()`.. are you sure its the right code you are showing?

Answer (score 11):

How about this:

```
return Members
    .Include("Files")
    .Where(m => m.Agreement.Equals(agreement) &&
                m.Files != null &&
               !m.Files.Any(f => f.Status.Equals(12)))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.7` this works fine:

```
var myEntity = await dbContext.MyEntities.Include(x => x.MyOtherEntities).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == "Not existing name");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
return Members.Include("Files")
                .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Agreement.Equals(agreement)
                 &&
                !m.Files.Any(f => f.Status==12));
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: @Hopeless `Equals` and `==`. Might be translated different by the provider

Comment: @JensKloster thanks for pointing out the difference, I did not see that this used `==` instead of `Equals`. However from the stacktrace looks like the exception is thrown when it does not even reach the server side, if it's a server side exception, the exception should be different.